# I have an issue in Parse Data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

I have worked in Xcode , It brings the news from a database In TableView , But News comes scattered , So that the first news table up to the top, and the new story comes down to the bottom .

This picture, explain what is meant

[image]

Comment: Show your PFQuery code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort directly inside your iOS Parse query (or if you use Parse butt code, in my butt code).

e.g.

```
[query orderByAscending:@"timestamp"];  // or dateCreated, dateUpdated, etc
```

More on [Parse website](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries)

Comment: wherever you make your PFQuery

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply sorting on array based on time. You can use sort descriptor for that. There is an example for that

```
   NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"time" ascending:YES];
    array = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptor];
```

Comment: Where you are getting data from database? You are getting array from database right?